# 503 service unavilable error on load cakephp controller

Tags: php, cakephp

I uploaded some files to overwrite existing files of the same name in a working cakephp project, and one of my models doesnt display.
My model Tutor  and all views now give a 503 service unavilable error. NOw all the other files work in the same project and same server .

My question is how do I go about debugging this? It works fine on my PC but not the remote server?

I have already tried to upload the file again.

I checked the error logs

Comment: Is there a controller named TutorsController.php ?

Comment: yes and I have no idea what to do? the same files work on my pc?

Comment: Your pc is windows i assume and the server linux?

Comment: yes, and on my model I added a virtual field  public $virtualFields = array(
        'full_name' => 'CONCAT(Tutor.first_name, " ", Tutor.last_name, " (", Tutor.id ,")")',
        'display_name' =>'CONCAT(Tutor.first_name, " ", Tutor.last_name)'
    );

Comment: Cakephp isnt giving you an error message, only 503 ?

Comment: no this is a cakephp issue because the problem is with 1 model

Comment: ok i solved it. On the tutorsController I had a foreach loop with nothing in it. I removed this and the problem went away. i recontructed the tutor controller again and this 1 new view was the issue. The error still doesnt make sense

Comment: looking for and finding a relevant error message in a log file (apache's) would explain what the problem with your unshown code was.

Comment: I sorted the problem out so why am I banned form usung this.

Comment: Please please I know the question was vague and I wont do this again but pkease let me post messages as this is the only resource i can use ... PLEASE LET ME POST

Comment: can this post be amended please as i cant post anymore

Answer (score 0):

This vague error was solved when  I had a foreach loop with nothing in it. I removed this and the problem went away.